# django call to custom method in model when rendering the page

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-2.0

If I have a custom method in my `Model` that I am calling in my `template`, does it mean there are multiple roundtrips happening from client(browser) to server?

I am pretty sure when I return `render()` from my view, rendering happens on the server side and the output as HTML is returned to the client.

Please correct me if my understanding is off.

Comment: No, since templates are *not* rendered by the client. The backend renders the *entire* response and sends it over to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Django renders at *server side*

Rendering happens at **server side**. If you thus write `{{ foo.bar }}` in your template, the client *never* knew that there was a `foo.bar` in the template. Substituting tags, etc. by (HTML)output is done by the Django render engine.

The *result* of that rendering is given to the client through a HTTP response. So the response itself, does not contain the *render logic*, it contains the "product" of the rendering. If you thus perform a `{{ SomeModel.objects.all() }}` in the template (given you of course passed a reference to the model), then it will typically result in an extra *database* query, but this is *not* managed by the client. The client does not know what logic the template is calling.

This can make an application more safe as well, since the client has no access to the template itself, and thus can not change the template to obtain sensitive information. Of course by designing specific query input, it can still aim to let the template return sensitive data.

Furthermore the template can contain some logic, that you do not want to share with the clients. By rendering it at the server, the client actually does not see how the HTML was rendered (of course an experienced developer can do some "guesswork" and after a while can have some ideas about how the rendering took place).

### But still the "product" of the rendering can result in *additional* calls

It is however possible that the result will result in extra calls. For example if your result contains `<img src="">`s, stylesheet links, etc. and other URLs, the browser typically will start fetching these as well. Furthermore if you define JavaScript that performs AJAX calls, these calls result in extra HTTP requests, but those are not done at *rendering* time of that specific template. These are "independent" calls later that again can result in rendering.

## Some technologies render at *client side*

Note that it does not per se is always that way. Some technologies, like Angular, do (most of) the rendering at the client side. In that case, there is JavaScript code that makes calls to the API, and then "unfolds" the "HTML" as specified by the developer. So it is perfectly possible to make a call to a webservice asking for tweets, and then let some JavaScript "inject" HTML code in the DOM to render the tweets accordingly. The advantage of this is that it makes it easy to change content dynamically (for example update the value of a certain product frequently in the browser).

This however requires that the data that is rendered is available through an API (well an API that can be accesses through HTTP requests), and those calls might need some extra security (for calls asking for data, the credentials usually need to be checked a second time).

Comment: so if i add MyModel.objects.all() and add it to the context but never display anything in the template related to MyModel's context, there is no database query happening due to lazy loading. is that correct?

Comment: @Asdfg: yes, `QuerySet`s are lazy, so if you do *not* consume them (for example by iterating, checking the number of objects, etc.), you normally never perform such query. Of course if you wrap a `list(..)` over the queryset (in the view), but never render the result, the `list(..)` forced the `QuerySet` to get evaluated. This is one of the reasons why it is better to pass `QuerySet`s instead of materialized lists to the template.

Comment: Thank you William. You are awesome.